# Grunt - pasta node_modules fora do projeto

Tags: javascript, node.js, front-end, grunt

Galera, estou iniciando em GruntJS, minha pasta node_modules tem 50MB, isso para cada projeto, fica ruim.

Gostaria de saber se tem como deixar uma pasta node_modules padrão em um local para utilizar em todos projetos sem precisar de ficar dentro da rais do projeto.

Obrigado

Exemplo:

meu projeto front-end hoje:

```
   nome-do-projeto
   ---node_modules(50mb)
   ---assets
      ---sass
       ---js
   ---build
       ---css
       ---js
```

Gostaria que a pasta node_modules, estive fora da raiz do projeto.

Comment: Está a falar do projeto no github, servidor, ou onde?

Comment: projeto front-end, vou tenta explicar melhor

Comment: Mas o motivo de tirar da raiz é pra diminuir o peso no repositório? Porque se for, é só ignorar esse diretório no sistema de controle de versão.

Comment: hoje ja utilizo a função de ignorar o node_modules, no SVN, porem queria alguma coisa diferente(melhor), antei pesquisando achei algumas coisas sobre instalar os plugins/dependencia como global

Comment: Realmente não vejo problema a pasta dentro do projeto, você pode me explicar no que isso atrapalha ?

Comment: Essa pode parecer uma pergunta retórica, mas você esta usando o `package.json` pra controlar suas dependências?

Comment: Lemos trabalho em uma agencia como front end, e  manipular uma pasta com 50MB dentro de cada projeto é ruim, se posso ter uma outra solução. Sim Gabriel uso package.json dentro do projeto para controlar as dependências.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cara, se você usa com frequência determinados módulos como Express, Grunt ou Gulp, você pode instala-los como módulos globais:

```
npm install -g nome_modulo
```

Dentro do seu projeto quando você for carregar uma dependência o Node vai procurar o seu modulo dentro do seu projeto(node_modules), caso não encontre ele vai procurar na pasta node_modules global.

Em Node geralmente não se versiona dependências. Uma boa prática é você criar um arquivo chamado package.json e definir suas dependências lá, quando alguém for baixar seu projeto será necessário apenas rodar o comando:

```
npm install
```

Assim o node baixa e instala as dependências do seu projeto.

Referências (em inglês):
[package.json](https://www.npmjs.org/doc/files/package.json.html)
[node_modules](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_modules)

Comment: Se não me engano, `npm install modulo --save` instala o modulo e adiciona ele nas dependencias do `package.json`.

Answer (score 0):

Uma dica que pode funcionar, mas não testei:

```
$ cd <global-modules-path>/node-google-timezone # vai para o diretório global do package
$ npm link                                      # cria um link global
$ cd ~/projects/my-node-project                 # vai para o diretório do seu projeto
$ npm link                                      # link-install do package
```

Referência: [NPM link](https://www.npmjs.org/doc/cli/npm-link.html)